# Pycharm Remote Python Interpreter over SSH Gateway, X11 forwarding

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to configure PyCharm 3.0 to use a Remote Python Interpreter.

The Problem is, I have to connect over a SSH Gateway:

MyMachine -> Gateway -> Machine with Python

When I connect via Cygwin I type the following: ssh -t user@gateway.com "ssh user@machineWithPython.com"

Is there a way to achieve this in PyCharm?
Another question, can I forward the X11 server to PyCharm (so that I can view the matplotlib plots on my machine?)

Regards,
m

Answer (score 6):

I was able to the piggyback X11 forwarding through another ssh connection.  Try setting the DISPLAY environment variable in your PyCharm run configuration like so:

DISPLAY=localhost:102

Check the value of DISPLAY in the other connection to see exactly what the value should be.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I have understood your question correctly, it is maybe more adequate for the UNiX/Linux part.

At you machine:

```
ssh -fN -L 2222:machinewithPython:22 \  user@gateway.com
```

This connects port 2222 on your local machine to port 22 on remotemachine,  and the ssh tunnnel will remain open until you kill the ssh process.

See the following links [here](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine) and [there](https://superuser.com/questions/193964/tunnelling-x11-through-an-ssh-gateway-with-no-x11-install).

Comment: Yes, thats correct, if you want to ssh on the console. But I want this setup in the PyCharm IDE and don't know if it's possible...